# Add image/panorama into PDF

Tags: python, pypdf, reportlab

I need to add an interactive panorama that I can potentially view in a PDF.

I was expecting an existing sample of this potentially using reportlab or pypdf2 but it doesn't seem to be the case here.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reportlab**. Create a Canvas object from the **reportlab** library and draw the image onto the **canvas** using the **drawImage** method. Then create a **PDFAnnotation** object, set its properties to make it interactive, and add it to the canvas using the **addAnnotation** method. Finally, save the canvas as a PDF file.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfdoc

def add_interactive_image_to_pdf(output_pdf_path, image_path, x, y, width, height):
    c = canvas.Canvas(output_pdf_path, pagesize=letter)

    # Load the image and add it to the canvas
    c.drawImage(image_path, x, y, width, height)

    # Add an interactive annotation
    image_annotation = pdfdoc.PDFAnnotation()
    image_annotation.setActive(True)
    image_annotation.setContents("Image Annotation")
    image_annotation.setRect([x, y, x + width, y + height])
    image_annotation.setBorderStyle(pdfdoc.BS_WIREFRAME)
    image_annotation.setFlags(pdfdoc.AN_PRINT | pdfdoc.AN_HIDE)

    c.addAnnotation(image_annotation)

    # Save the PDF
    c.save()

    print(f"Image added to {output_pdf_path} successfully.")


# Example usage
output_pdf_path = "output.pdf"
image_path = "image.png"
x = 100  # X-coordinate of the image position
y = 100  # Y-coordinate of the image position
width = 200  # Width of the image
height = 150  # Height of the image

add_interactive_image_to_pdf(output_pdf_path, image_path, x, y, width, height)
```